# PDF export in a Shiny App with Plotly charts, HTML template and parameters

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I have a quite large Shiny application with dozens of plotly charts (and many tables and calculations) that can be used online, but the main feature is that clients generate PDFs. The PDF generation is done now on the client side, i.e. with clients browser (IE) and their locally installed digital printer using specially prepared HTML template & CSS file for the optimal layout that covers a long list of the very specific PDF design requirements that cannot be covered easly with RMD.

The solution is far from the optimal as it requires "a lot of clicks" for the end users and is very sensitive to any client's local settings (like print margins) which are not always possible to set with the CSS file.

**My questions is:**
is it possible to shift the PDF generation to the server side as sort of digital printer that is installed on the server, so all the layout requirements are covered and user's parameters (like date) are applied, ideally without a need to recalculate everything to get the results? I was already considering writting this in LaTeX, but it would be a very complicated job due to very specific layout requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [page in the Shiny documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/generating-reports.html) about this exact topic. Basically you create a `report.Rmd` that takes the user inputs and uses it as variables for printed plots.

[Here is a working example with HTML output.](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/generating-reports.html)

**edit**: Didn't see your design requirements at first, sorry. Maybe those can be covered using a LaTeX background or the like?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have spent many hours (and few tousands lines of code) to tune every pixel of that report in HTML + CSS, so recreating this in LaTeX would be a very hard job, especially that I have only a rudimental LaTeX knowledge.